# MWS Post Request with Google Scripts

Tags: javascript, post, google-apps-script, amazon-mws

I am trying to make a post request through google scripts to amazon to collect information.

We are trying to get our orders to MWS and transfer them to sheets automatically.

I got to the last step which is signing the request.

A few things I wasnt sure about:

1. They say we use the secret key for hashing,I only see a client secret 
    and an access key id, which do I use?
2. Do I add the URL as part of whats getting signed? On the MWS Scratch pad they add this as shown:

`POST
mws.amazonservices.com
/Orders/2013-09-01`

Does it have to be on separate lines does it need post and the rest of the stuff. Its a little unclear.?

3. I read online that the sha256 byte code gets base64 encoded, not the string literal, is that true?
4. I tried to hash the string that amazon gave to me with an online tool and compare it to the hash they provided and the base64 encode, thing matched. I tried decoding as well, nothing matched

Can someone please send me an example that works, so I can understand what happens and how it works?

Thank you!

Below is what I have so far:

```
function POSTRequest() {

  var url = 'https:mws.amazonservices.com/Orders/2013-09-01?';

  var today = new Date();
  var todayTime = ISODateString(today);

  var yesterday = new Date();
  yesterday.setDate(today.getDate() - 1);
  yesterday.setHours(0,0,0,0);
  var yesterdayTime = ISODateString(yesterday); 

  var dayBeforeYesterday = new Date();
  dayBeforeYesterday.setDate(today.getDate() - 2);
  dayBeforeYesterday.setHours(0,0,0,0);
  var dayBeforeYesterdayTime = ISODateString(dayBeforeYesterday); 

  var unsignedURL = 
  'POST\r\nhttps:mws.amazonservices.com\r\n/Orders/2013-09-01\r\n'+
  'AWSAccessKeyId=xxxxxxxxxxx' +
  '&Action=ListOrders'+
  '&CreatedAfter=' + dayBeforeYesterdayTime +
  '&CreatedBefore' + yesterdayTime +
  '&FulfillmentChannel.Channel.1=AFN' +
  '&MWSAuthToken=xxxxxxxxxxxx'+
  '&MarketplaceId.Id.1=ATVPDKIKX0DER' +
  '&SellerId=xxxxxxxxxxx'+
  '&SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256'+
  '&SignatureVersion=2'+
  '&Timestamp='+ ISODateString(new Date) + 
  '&Version=2013-09-0';

  var formData = {
        'AWSAccessKeyId' : 'xxxxxxxxx',
        'Action' : "ListOrders",
        'CreatedAfter' : dayBeforeYesterdayTime,
        'CreatedBefore' : yesterdayTime,
        'FulfillmentChannel.Channel.1' : 'AFN',
        'MWSAuthToken' : 'xxxxxxxxxxxx',
        'MarketplaceId.Id.1' : 'ATVPDKIKX0DER',
        'SellerId' : 'xxxxxxxxxx',
        'SignatureMethod' : 'HmacSHA256',
        'SignatureVersion' : '2',
        'Timestamp' : ISODateString(new Date),
        'Version' : '2013-09-01',
        'Signature' : calculatedSignature(unsignedURL)

      };

   var options = {
     "method" : "post",
     "muteHttpExceptions" : true,
     "payload" : formData
   };


  var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  writeDataToXML(result);
  Logger.log(result);


  if (result.getResponseCode() == 200) {
  writeDataToXML(result);
  }
}




function calculatedSignature(url) {
var urlToSign = url;
var secret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
var accesskeyid = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';

  var byteSignature = Utilities.computeHmacSha256Signature(urlToSign, secret);
// convert byte array to hex string
var signature = byteSignature.reduce(function(str,chr){
  chr = (chr < 0 ? chr + 256 : chr).toString(16);
  return str + (chr.length==1?'0':'') + chr;
},'');


  Logger.log("URL to sign: " + urlToSign);
  Logger.log("");
  Logger.log("byte " + byteSignature);
  Logger.log("");
  Logger.log("reg " + signature);

var byte64 =  Utilities.base64Encode(byteSignature)
Logger.log("base64 byte " + Utilities.base64Encode(byteSignature));
  Logger.log("");
Logger.log("base64 reg " + Utilities.base64Encode(signature)); 

 return byte64;
}
```

Comment: can i have your working script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Step 1, creating the string to be signed**

The `string_to_sign` is the combination of the following:

- The string `POST` followed by a `NEWLINE` character
- The name of the host, `mws.amazonservices.com`, followed by a `NEWLINE`
- The API URL, often just `/`, or somthing like `/Orders/2013-09-01`, followed by a `NEWLINE`
- An alphabetical list of all parameters except `Signature` in URL encoding, like `a=1&b=2`, not followed by anything

The minimum parameters seem to be the following:

- `AWSAccessKeyId` is a 20-character code provided by Amazon
- `Action` is the name of your API call, like `GetReport`
- `SellerId` is your 14-character seller ID
- `SignatureMethod` is `HmacSHA256`
- `SignatureVersion` is `2`
- `Timestamp` is a date like `20181231T23:59:59Z` for one second before new year UTC
- `Version` is the API version like `2013-09-01`
- additional parameters *may* be needed for your call, depending on the value of `Action`

*Please note:*

- The `NEWLINE` character is just "\n", not "\r\n"
- The name of the host should *not* include "https://" or "http://"
- The `Signature` parameter is necessary for the actual call later (see step 3), but is *not* part of the `string_to_sign`.

Your `string_to_sign` should now look somewhat like this:

```
POST
mws.amazonservices.com
/Orders/2013-09-01
AWSAccessKeyId=12345678901234567890&Action=ListOrders&CreatedAfter .... &Version=2013-09-01
```

**Step 2, signing that string**

- Calculate a SHA256 hash of above string using the 40-character `Secret Key`
- Encode this hash using Base64
- In Pseudocode: `signature = Base64encode( SHA256( string_to_sign, secret_key ))`

**Step 3, send the call**

Send a HTTPS POST request, using the full alphabetical list of parameters, now *including* above signature as `Signature` somewhere in the middle, because you need to keep ascending alphabetical order.

`https://mws.amazonservices.com/Orders/2013-09-01?AWSAccessKeyId....Version=2013-09-01`

**Step 4, processing the result**

You should be getting two things back: a response header and a XML document. Be sure to evaluate the HTTP status in the header as well as all contents of the XML document. Some error messages are hidden deeply in XML while HTTP returns "200 OK".

**Step 5, Advanced Stuff**

If you use calls that require you to send a document, like `SendFeed`, you need to do the following additional steps:

- Calculate the MD5 hash of your document
- Encode this hash using Base64
- In Pseudocode: `contentmd5= Base64encode( MD5( document ))`
- Add `Content-Type: text/xml` (or whatever fits your document) as HTTP header
- Add `Content-MD5:` plus the base64 encoded hash as HTTP header

Answer (score 0):

This code was a great help for building a similar application. I corrected some small issues to bring it up to work:

before signing the ISODate need to be worked out to replace the ":" chars

```
  var todayTime = ISODateString(today);
  var todayISO = todayTime;


  var todayTime_ = todayTime.replace(":", "%3A");
  todayTime = todayTime_.replace(":","%3A");
```

The same for the calculated signature (quick & dirty solution, replace only 3 appearences and need to updated for more chars)

```
  Logger.log(unsignedURL);

  var tmpsignature = calculatedSignature(unsignedURL);

  var orsignature = tmpsignature;


// encode special chars
tmpsignature = encodeURIComponent(orsignature);
  }
```

I added a header and dropped the form, put all parameters in the url

```
var header = {
     "x-amazon-user-agent": "GoogleSheets/1.0 (Language=Javascript)",
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
     //  "Content-Type": "text/xml"
}; 


   var options = {
     "method" : "post",
     "muteHttpExceptions" : true,
   //  "payload" : formData,
     "header":header
   };
```

And changed the call to url encoded (Form was not working, do not know why)

```
var url = 'https:mws-eu.amazonservices.com/Orders/2013-09-01?'+
'AWSAccessKeyId=<your stuff>'+
'&Action=GetOrder'+
  '&SellerId=<your stuff>+
  '&MWSAuthToken=<your token>'+
  '&SignatureVersion=2'+
  '&Timestamp='+todayTime'+ // remember to replace the ":" thru hex
  '&Version=2013-09-01'+
  '&Signature='+ tmpsignature+
  '&SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256'+
  '&AmazonOrderId.Id.1='+<your order;
```

parsed the response:

```
 var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);

  //writeDataToXML(result);
  Logger.log(result);

    var xml = result.getContentText();

  var document = XmlService.parse(xml);
```

This worked! :-)

I checked the signature also with 
https://mws-eu.amazonservices.com/scratchpad/index.html